# Place checkbox/radio tags BEFORE labels

Tags: html, css, symfony, checkbox, twig

I use this Twig code to display checkboxes (or radio) of my Symfony form:

```
{% for o in my_form.magic_choices %}
    {{ form_row(o) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This generates following output for each choice:

```
<div>
    <label for="myform_magic_choices_0">Secret option</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="secret_option" ...>
</div>
```

This forces `checkbox` input element to be **after** its `label` visually, how do i fix this to make my choice lists better? I need to make **checks to be in a left side**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

twig

```
{{ form_row(o, {'attr': {'class': 'checkboxy'}}) }}
```

css

```
checkboxy {
    float:left;
}
```

Well, this was not mentioned in Symfony Docs and this is the epic fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply float the input left.

Comment: yes, but Symfony ignores `'attr' => array(
                    'style' => 'float:left;'
                ),` (attr) in form builder

Comment: I don't know enough about Symfony adding inline styles, but if you target it the input from a CSS file, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than render using `form_row` render the item individually like..

```
<div class="checkbox{% if o.vars.errors|length > 0 %} has-error{% endif %}">
    {{ form_widget(o) }} {{ form_label(o) }}
    {% if o.vars.errors|length > 0 %}
        <span class="help_block">{{ form_errors(o) }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

The actual Bootstrap layout using the "checkbox" class has the `input` element inside the `label` and uses a margin-left for the `input` so that renders correctly so you might want to override the CSS for that.

```
.checkbox input[type=checkbox],
.checkbox-inline input[type=checkbox],
.radio input[type=radio],
.radio-inline input[type=radio] {
    // margin-left: -20px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

**Alternatively**

You could render the label as text so that it conforms to the Bootstrap thinking like..

```
<div class="checkbox{% if o.vars.errors|length > 0 %} has-error{% endif %}">
    <label>
        {{ form_widget(o) }} {{ o.vars.label }}
    </label>
    {% if o.vars.errors|length > 0 %}
        <span class="help_block">{{ form_errors(o) }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this is funny and too long. Thanks!